# How to find all siblings and half-siblings

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to find out if Table_3  contains ALL of the siblings  to a child which belongs to a certain parent. 
For example I ask about child 12 (parent 1 = Charles). Table_2 tells me he has 2 more siblings 14 and 23. Now , how do I write a SQL code to find out if Table_3 contains ALL of the children, and then and ONLY then flag up or do something about it?

Table_1

```
id | parent     
1  | Charles    
2  | Jack
```

Table_2

```
P_Id | chld_Id 
 1   | 12    
 1   | 14 
 1   | 23
 2   | 7
 2   | 13
```

Table_3

```
chld_Id
 5 
 7 
 12 
 16 
 14 
 23 
 25
```

EDIT: Formatting the table
I forgot to mention that I use mySQL and PHP

Comment: Oh no! I can´t format the table as it should look like :O what to do? please help

Comment: @Manari . . . Please edit the question and show the *results* that you are looking for.

Comment: It looks like table_1 isn't even necessary.  A simple left join of table_1 and table_3 will get you what you want.

Comment: @vol7ron Youre right. At this point table1 is not necessary. You mean LEFT JOIN of table2 and table3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parents of child 12 with:

```
 select tt2.parent from table_2 tt2 where tt2.child_id = 12;
```

You can get the other children of those parents:

```
select t2.*
from table_2 t2
where t2.parent in (select tt2.parent from table_2 tt2 where tt2.child_id = 12);
```

You can check if they are missing in `table_3`:

```
select t2.*
from table_2 t2
where t2.parent in (select tt2.parent from table_2 tt2 where tt2.child_id = 12) and
      not exists (select 1 from table_3 t3 where t2.child_id = t3.child_id);
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks. Now how would I do to include the parent name, Charles in this case? This is the results I want to get! The name of the parent (when ALL of the children are present)

Comment: @Mansari . . . That is a different question, which you should ask as a new question and not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/977001/34/0)

```
SELECT     table_2.chld_Id
         , SUM(
             CASE WHEN table_3.chld_Id IS NULL 
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 0
             END
           ) unfound_siblings

FROM      table_2 
JOIN      ( select p_Id from table_2 where chld_Id = 7 ) parent ON ( table_2.p_Id = parent.p_Id ) 
LEFT JOIN table_3  ON ( table_2.chld_Id = table_3.chld_Id ) 
GROUP BY  table_2.chld_Id
;
```

If you wanted the Parent ID, like what you said in another comment, just add it the field list and t o the `group by`.

- In place of the `sum` line you could put `, count(table_3.chld_Id) found_siblings` to do the reverse